# Forcing user to enable iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud

We are developing an app where we need to store some information in iCloud and that should be synched across the devices.

For this to happen we should force the user to enable the iCloud for the app. Can we do something like,

After launching the app just check whether the iCloud is enabled for the app, if not alert the user to enable the iCloud and try again? Without enabling iCloud we don't allow user to get in to the app.

Will Apple allow doing this?

I think we can't force user to enable the iCloud and it is up to them enable it or not. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I can't imagine you would be able to. If I was a user who didn't use iCloud and your app attempted to FORCE me to use iCloud, I'd uninstall it immediately.

Comment: well wat u want to do is possible , it will b like an alert

Comment: For many users this will be a deal breaker and they won't use your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. You can't force a user to enable iCloud on their device. And that is a good thing.

You need to rethink this. What about users with only one device. There is no point to forcing such users to use iCloud with your app. There are no other devices to sync with.

In the end, you can check to see if iCloud is available or not. If not, you can tell the user that your app does require it (for some unknown reason) and prevent them from continuing.

No one here can say for sure if Apple will allow this or not. I know that as a user, I would not be happy with an app that only worked if iCloud was enabled. It should be the user's choice.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs on this. I will post this question in Apple developer forum just to check whether Apple allows doing this. With user perspective, I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

See for this you have to check if iCloud is installed in the device . So use this code in your

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  NSURL *iCloudURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
  NSLog(@"%@", [iCloudURL absoluteString]);

  if(iCloudURL){
    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *iCloudStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
    [iCloudStore setString:@"Success" forKey:@"iCloudStatus"];
    [iCloudStore synchronize]; // For Synchronizing with iCloud Server
    NSLog(@"iCloud status : %@", [iCloudStore stringForKey:@"iCloudStatus"]);
   }
}
```

This will check the iCloud Status . Here you can put a check for the true and false case and if it is false you can exit the app with an alert for the user to try again when his iCloud is enabled from the settings.

Hope this helps !! :)

**PS :-** Of Course for implementing the above code you would first have to do the necessities of implementing the entitlements and basics of iCloud which you would know i presume .

Comment: Listen it is the users phone ... you cant force him to do anything ... wat u can do is not let him open the app till he implements iCloud ...